# conf or .htaccess-- when to use which?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Apache URL rewrite logic can be written either in conf or .htaccess file. Which one is more suitable, for which occasion? And let's say I have .htaccess in my web root directory, and I have a conf file defined on Apache/conf directory also, which file will kick in first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address just one part of your question: if you don't need the increased flexibility of a `.htaccess` file in different directories, don't use them; they slow down processing of requests.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess file resides in the root folder, and can easily be copied to another destination together with web the pages. Conf file may not always be accessible in a hosted environment.

Answer (score 0):

The .conf file mod_rewrite directives will occur first -- before the URL-to-filename translation phase. But for most cases, that difference will be minimal. There are performance considerations, but they only really affect very heavily trafficked sites or underpowered hardware.